# Django with urls.py importing app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My project was running; When cleaning .pyc, he stopped recognizing routes apps I created within it.
The directory structure is as follows and In the main urls.py, I have the following:

[image]

Now I released the following error:

```
No module named dorna.rest.v1.urls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urls.py` seem to be inside dorona folder, try to import rest directly:

```
(r'^v1/', include('rest.v1.urls')),
```

Comment: This was part of the problem; I forgot to put in the initial situation before making the screenshot. Sorry.

The main problema was that i delete the __initial__.pyc in all the proyect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have added `dorna` twice. You probably don't have to do that as can be seen from your `'^admin/'` route.

Thus, `include('dorna.rest.v1.urls')` instead of `include('dorna.dorna.rest.v1.urls')` should work.